# Как реализовать автоматический переход на страницу из корня сайта?

Tags: php

Как реализовать переход со страницы http://site.com  на страницу http://site.com/ferst/index.php?

Comment: `<a href="/ferst/index.php">переход</a>`? Опишите в чем конкретно вопрос ваш.

Comment: Дело в том что у меня лежат  ferst лежит в menus/ferst/index.php/  B и когда я подключаю, то в URL site.com/menu/ferst/index.php. Ну и хотоелось бы перебрать всю дериикртоию в цикле что ли

Answer (score 1):

В основе редиректа на php лежит использование функции (справка):

```
header ( string $string [, bool $replace = true [, int $http_response_code ]] )
```

Где:

- `$string` — строка заголовка;
- `$replace` — необязательный параметр, означающий, нужно ли перезаписывать ранее указанный аналогичный заголовок, отправленный в браузер пользователя (по умолчанию равен `true`);
- `$http_response_code` — необязательный параметр принудительного задания кода HTTP ответа, если таковой не был задан в ранее переданном заголовке, и строка заголовка при этом не пуста. По умолчанию передается код `302 Moved Temporarily` («временно перемещено»).

Для того, чтобы осуществить непосредственный редирект, необходимо, чтобы был указан специальный вид строки заголовка `location: …`. Например, так:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```